# show label of an object property in struts2 text tag

Tags: struts2, label, resourcebundle

I want to show a property of an object in my Jsp page. the problem is that this property is the name of a label in my resource bundle and the only way I know is to use `<s:text name="labelname">` but now that it's a property of an object, I don't know how to do this. This is a part of my code, 'brandList' is a list of brand objects and 'brandName' field is name of label. I want something like this

```
       <s:iterator value="brandList" status="stat">
            <s:text name="<s:property value='brandName'>" />
       </s:iterator>
```

but this doesn't work. any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:iterator value="brandList" status="stat" var="brandName">
    <s:text name="%{brandName}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but It says attribute var is not defined for iterator tag.

Comment: Alright, `id` has been deprecated and `var` is to be used in newer versions of Struts 2 (http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/iterator.html)